# Type hints for a Python variadic with a return type that depends on parameter types

Tags: python, variadic-functions, typing

Consider the definition of `inner_join` below:

```
from typing import TypeVar
from collections.abc import Mapping, Hashable
from functools import reduce

K = TypeVar('K', bound=Hashable)
V = TypeVar('V')

def keyset(m: Mapping[K, Any]) -> set[K]:
    return set(m.keys())

def inner_join(*ms: Mapping[K, Any]) -> dict[K, tuple[...]]:
    keys = reduce(set.intersection, map(keyset, ms)) if ms else set()

    return {k: tuple(m[k] for m in ms) for k in keys}
```

My understanding is the type hint for `inner_join` is correct, but it is much less specific than it could be, provided I could somehow express the fact that the types of the elements of the `tuple` is fixed by the types of the values of the mappings `ms`. For instance, if I were declaring a two-arg version of this function, I would write the type as follows:

```
U = TypeVar('U')
V = TypeVar('V')

def inner_join2(m1: Mapping[K, U], m2: Mapping[K, V]) -> dict[K, tuple[U, V]]:
   ...
```

Is there any way to generalize that annotation so it works for the variadic version?

Comment: these annotations should use square brackets `-> set(K)` i.e. `-> set[K]` and same here `-> dict(K, tuple[...])`

Comment: and `'U' = TypeVar('U')` should be `U = TypeVar('U')`

Comment: You would need some concept of type-level containers/programming that Python currently lacks. Think of something like `def inner_join_var(*ms: [Mapping[K, x] for x in Us]) -> dict[K, Us])`. In particular, you wouldn't be *saying* what types the elements of `ms` has, but rather trying to *capture* what types they are (or will be).

Comment: Aren't you missing a star?.. It probably should be `def inner_join(*ms: Mapping...` Also `tuple[...]` is invalid annotation, you probably want `tuple[Any, ...]`.

Comment: There is nothing to do here until [PEP646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) is implemented, but it isn't possible even with help of it. You need something like `map` to interpret `Mapping[str, *_TT]` as `[Mapping[str, *_T] for _T in _TT]`.